# In Geoserver 2.15.1 Postgis datastore not visible even i created postgis datastore previously

Tags: postgis, geoserver, datastore, postgresql-11

I am setting up a webapp using Geoserver and PostgreSQL. Once I created postgis datastore and configured all layers and layergroups. I didn't even close my computer but when I started again working with Geoserver can't reach the layer preview, I checked and seen that there is no option visible for adding postgis datastore. Before that I installed css and backup&restore extensions, and don't know maybe it is not relevant but my computer closed suddenly because of power off even that ı was able to reach datastore after power off. Additionaly I renamed the datastore name that i created.

I tried to reinstall geoserver and postgis but not fixed.

Here is the error:

```java
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to find the datastore factory for kadikoygis_itrf, did you forget to install the store extension jar?
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getDataStore(ResourcePool.java:535)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getCacheableFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:916)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.tryGetFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:901)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:893)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getFeatureType(ResourcePool.java:878)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.FeatureTypeInfoImpl.getFeatureType(FeatureTypeInfoImpl.java:123)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor275.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:127)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getFeatureType(Unknown Source)
        at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.checkStyle(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:1215)
        ... 102 more
```

Comment: so do you have the postgres jar? (tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-*.jar)

Comment: yes, there is postgresql-42.1.1.jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After remove and reinstallation it solved.